# Installing the PHP Language for Vert.x

Tags: php, git, maven, vert.x

I'm trying to install the PHP language in my vert.x mods directory. I have tried both branches and both process a different answer.

All these results and errors were either produced when trying to build from the git repo or using running `vertx run app.php` in the command line using this simple PHP script:

```
<?php

use Vertx\Pump;

$server = Vertx::createNetServer();

$server->connectHandler(function($socket) {
        $pump = new Pump($socket, $socket);
        $pump->start();
})->listen(1234, 'localhost');
```

When I try running the current master branch, this is what Maven tells me:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running io.vertx.lang.php.integration.PhpIntegrationTests
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Starting test: src/test/resources/buffer|buffer_test.php|testMagic
feb 08, 2014 9:25:37 PM org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate error
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.vertx.lang.php.PhpVerticleFactory.close(PhpVerticleFactory.java:245)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleReference.decRef(ModuleReference.java:61)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$23.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1816)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$23.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1814)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.callHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:73)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.checkDone(CountingCompletionHandler.java:91)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.setHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:68)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1814)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1738)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.handleDeployFailure(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1702)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$1900(DefaultPlatformManager.java:59)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$20.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1664)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:176)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

feb 08, 2014 9:25:37 PM org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate error
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.vertx.lang.php.PhpVerticleFactory.close(PhpVerticleFactory.java:245)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleReference.decRef(ModuleReference.java:61)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$23.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1816)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$23.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1814)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.callHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:73)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.checkDone(CountingCompletionHandler.java:91)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.setHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:68)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1814)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1738)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.handleDeployFailure(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1702)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$1900(DefaultPlatformManager.java:59)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$20.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1664)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:176)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.322 sec <<< FAILURE!
io.vertx.lang.php.integration.PhpIntegrationTests  Time elapsed: 30.014 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Timed out waiting for test to complete
    at org.vertx.testtools.JavaClassRunner.waitForLatch(JavaClassRunner.java:329)
    at org.vertx.testtools.JavaClassRunner.runChild(JavaClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.vertx.testtools.JavaClassRunner.runChild(JavaClassRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)


Results :

Failed tests:
   Timed out waiting for test to complete

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ lang-php ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/mriemers/Projects/Vertx LazyFIFA Autobuyer PHP/mod-lang-php/target/lang-php-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14:verify (default) @ lang-php ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/mriemers/Projects/Vertx LazyFIFA Autobuyer PHP/mod-lang-php/target/failsafe-reports
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.910s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 08 21:26:07 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14:verify (default) on project lang-php: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/mriemers/Projects/Vertx LazyFIFA Autobuyer PHP/mod-lang-php/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And this is what Vert.x tells me when I try to run the very simple PHP script:

```
Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.vertx.lang.php.PhpVerticleFactory.close(PhpVerticleFactory.java:245)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleReference.decRef(ModuleReference.java:61)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$24.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1852)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$24.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1850)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.callHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:73)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.checkDone(CountingCompletionHandler.java:91)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.setHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:68)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1850)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1774)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.handleDeployFailure(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1738)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$2000(DefaultPlatformManager.java:56)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1700)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:176)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.vertx.lang.php.PhpVerticleFactory.close(PhpVerticleFactory.java:245)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleReference.decRef(ModuleReference.java:61)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$24.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1852)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$24.handle(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1850)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.callHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:73)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.checkDone(CountingCompletionHandler.java:91)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.CountingCompletionHandler.setHandler(CountingCompletionHandler.java:68)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1850)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doUndeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1774)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.handleDeployFailure(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1738)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$2000(DefaultPlatformManager.java:56)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1700)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:176)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It keeps going like this and I have to eventually ^C it to let it stop.

But when I try to build the `eventbus-bridge` branch Maven returns a lot of:

```
src/test/resources/http|route_matcher_test.php|testGetWithRegex(io.vertx.lang.php.integration.PhpIntegrationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.013 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.vertx.java.core.VertxException: route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
        at io.vertx.lang.php.PhpVerticleFactory.createVerticle(PhpVerticleFactory.java:180)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$20.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1662)
        at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:176)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And ends with this:

```
Tests in error:
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx buffer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx context_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx context_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx deploy_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx deploy_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx deploy_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx deploy_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx deploy_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx eventbus_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx filesystem_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx http_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx route_matcher_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx include_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx include_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx include_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx net_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx net_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx net_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx net_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx record_parser_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx shareddata_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx shareddata_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx shareddata_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx shareddata_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx shareddata_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx timer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.
   » Vertx timer_test.php is not a valid PHP verticle.

Tests run: 98, Failures: 0, Errors: 98, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ lang-php ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/mriemers/Projects/Vertx LazyFIFA Autobuyer PHP/mod-lang-php/target/lang-php-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14:verify (default) @ lang-php ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/mriemers/Projects/Vertx LazyFIFA Autobuyer PHP/mod-lang-php/target/failsafe-reports
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.238s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 08 21:09:38 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/51M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.14:verify (default) on project lang-php: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/mriemers/Projects/Vertx LazyFIFA Autobuyer PHP/mod-lang-php/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And when I run the script using `vertx run app.php` this is what it returns to me:

> app.php is not a valid PHP verticle.

Comment: Hi martijn. I've pushed a few changes to the PHP module. This seems to have been a bug introduced with a new feature. While the PHP module is still under development, the current build should be stable. Let me know if you have any more issues.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the `app.php is not a valid PHP verticle.` error...

Comment: Did you pull and install the master branch again? Have the other errors gone away? If you're getting `not a valid PHP verticle` then that simply indicates that the PHP module can't find the verticle you're trying to run. So, it's simply a check that the file exists, and if the PHP module can't open the file then that exception is thrown. Are you sure you're running the verticle from the same directory? All the PHP tests are passing (and they should have passed when you installed it with `mvn install`) so it should work since the tests are working...

Comment: It's possible that Vert.x pulled a bad version of the PHP module into its `sys-mods` directory. You should check in the `sys-mods` directory and delete the PHP module in that directory and then try to run it again. Vert.x would not have picked up the updated version you pulled from GitHub.

Comment: As long as the PHP module doesn't have an official release you may have to remove the module from the `sys-mods` directory to update it. Hopefully an early version will be released soon though (within the month).